# Transitive methods, is this a sign of bad code?

Tags: php, refactoring

lets imagine a class:

```
class A
{
    public function m1()
    {
         $this->m2();
         $this->m3();
         $this->m4();
    }

    private function m2()
    {
    }

    private function m3()
    {
    }

    private function m4()
    {
        $this->m5();
        $this->m6();
    }

    private function m5()
    {
    }

    private function m6()
    {
    }
}
```

I think `m1()`, `m2()`, `m3()`, `m4()` are fine, but `m5()`, `m6()` should be in another class, because `m5()`, `m6()` only works for `m5()` (and can be used only with `m4()`). Is that fine?

Answer (score 1):

Your example is too abstract as to select a single strategy of refactor.

Yet you can have a look to [php traits](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php) if you are 5.4 or above.

In your case I would move `m4` `m5` `m6` into a trait.

Still, as said before, at this point I cannot think about code reuse because its a very abstract example. But one of the advantages of traits is easy reuse and cleaner code. Hope it helps.